# How to add LastDayOfMonth to a warehouse date view

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

We currently have this view for Date in our warehouse:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vw_DimDate] AS
SELECT
    D.DateKey
    , D.DayMarker AS DayMarker
    , D.Year_YYYY as CalendarYear
    , D.Quarter_QQ as QuarterName
    , D.Quarter_QQ + ' - ' + D.Year_YYYY AS CalendarQuarterName
    , D.Month_MMM as MonthShortName
    , D.Month_MMMM as MonthName
    , D.Month_MMMM + ' ' + D.Year_YYYY AS CalendarMonthName
    , D.Week_WW as WeekName
    , D.Week_WW + ' - ' + D.Year_YYYY AS CalendarWeekName
    , D.Day_DD + ' ' + D.Month_MMMM + ' ' + D.Year_YYYY AS CalendarDayName
    , D.DayOfWeekName
    ,convert(datetime,'01 ' + Month_MMM + ' ' + D.Year_YYYY) as FirstDayOfMonth
    --<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<as LastDayOfMonth 
    , W.WeekYear_YYYY as Week_Year
    , W.Week_WW + ' ' + W.WeekYear_YYYY as Week_YearWeekName
FROM
    WHData..TB_DimDate D
JOIN
    WHData..tb_DimDateWeek W
    on D.DateKey = W.DateKey
where
    D.DateKey < convert(char(8),getdate(),112)
```

I'd like to add a field for `LastDayOfMonth` - what is the standard implementation for this?

Comment: If one day you move to SQL Server 2012, there's a built in function for this - [EOMONTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh213020.aspx).

Comment: Many date fns examples including first/last day of week, month etc...: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/29/sql-server-few-useful-datetime-functions-to-find-specific-dates/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Last Day of the Month, you can use:

```
DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE())+1, 0))
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7821).

If you had a date column in your table, then you would replace `GetDate()` with your column.  From your current query it looks like that is the `DateKey`, so you would use:

```
DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, D.DateKey)+1, 0))
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87e30/2)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to add 1 month, then add "-1" days to that FirstDayOfMonth.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `D.Year_YYYY` & `Month_MMM` are string types

```
dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month, 1, D.Year_YYYY + right('0'+ Month_MMM,2) + '01'))
                                                             as LastDayOfMonth
```

Also it is better to change your `FirstDayOfMonth` to `ISO format` before converting as;

```
convert(datetime,D.Year_YYYY + right('0'+ Month_MMM,2) + '01') as FirstDayOfMonth
```

Answer (score 1):

One more option

```
DATEADD(dd , - DAY([Date]), DATEADD(MONTH , 1, [Date]))
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3930/1/0)

Comment: +1 thanks for the extra option; lots of ways to skin this cat

Comment: uh-huh)) and it is my favourite way. tnx